# Apache is not even starting after updating

Tags: apache2, php

`sudo apache2ctl start`

```
[Tue Jun 24 17:53:38 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
httpd (pid 4924) already running
```

After running the above command to start apache2, I get this error.
Please someone help me, I am not able to run php on my computer due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that apache2 is already running.
If it's not working try restarting it with : `[sudo] apache2ctl restart`